# How to only extract text fields from a PDF using iTextSharp C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to extract data entered into a form by users from a PDF file. The file consists of a few basic fields such as First Name, Surname, Date of Birth etc. The user will fill these fields in and send back the document. I am only interested in extracting the text fields where they have entered their data. Here is the code I have so far, which returns all of the data within the PDF:

```
public static string extractedText()
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    string filepath, text;
    dlg.Filter = "PDF Files(*.PDF)|*.PDF|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filepath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
        string strText = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                string s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);
                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s;
                text = strText;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return strText;
    } 
    else 
        return "abc";
}
```

The above code successfully returns all the data, however, I only need a select few fields (text fields). How can I be more specific about the data I am extracting?

Comment: If text extraction like in the code you posted returns you all the values, then you don't appear to have any AcroForm fields but merely some drawings that look like firm fields.